# Get ID or Class of clicked object

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a simple plugin, so when the user clicks on the photo, he gets a bigger photo (because all photos are smaller that the real ones). And my question is, how can this bigger photo close when the user clicks on `body` or `html`, but it shouldn't close it if it was clicked on the photo? It probably should look like this:

```
$('body, html').click(function() {

   if(clickedOnPhoto)

      //do nothing

   else

     //close the photo

})
```

Comment: @amnotiam: He wants to get the `id` of the clicked target and check if it's the enlarged image before resizing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than checking what the target was and deciding what to do; you can add a `click` event handler to the `document` element to close big photos and add a `click` event handler to the big photos that stops the propagation of the `click` event so it doesn't reach the `document` element:

```
$('#photo-container').on('click', '.big-photo-elements', function (event) {
    //stop the event from propagating normally so that it does not reach the `document` element
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function () {
    //run code to close big photos, this will not be triggered if a user clicks on the big photo
    $('.big-photo-elements').hide();
});
```

Comment: +1 I think the `stopPropagation` approach is a better way to go. Simple and low maintenance.

Comment: @Jasper: Actually I like this method better. Could you explain me a little bit what is written? Thanks anyway. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var id = e.target.id; // get the id attribute of the target of the click
    if( id === 'yourDivId' ) {
        // photo was clicked
    } else {
        // something else was clicked
    }
});
```

Comment: Great, what about class instead of id?

Comment: You mean `e.target.className` which returns a string containing the class attribute (normally space separated if there are more than one class)

Answer (score 0):

The [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) will give you the leaf-most element that was clicked. You can wrap it into `$()` to perform any class/attribute checks you like via jQuery